# React Native - Local push notifications are not fired sometimes in IOS

Tags: ios, iphone, react-native, notifications, react-native-push-notification

In my application, local notifications are not fired sometimes.There is no specific case.It is fired sometimes but sometimes is not.

I see that all of notifications are correctly setted (scheduleded) but it does not fire notificaiton.

Device:
iPhone 6 - iOS 10.3.3
iPhone 6 - iOS 11.1.2

```
          LocalNotifService.scheduleNotif(date,"message",mp3NameOntime);
```

My notification service:

```
static scheduleNotif(date,message,sound) {
    PushNotification.localNotificationSchedule({
      date: date, 

      /* Android Only Properties */
      ticker: "Notification Ticker",
      autoCancel: true, 
      largeIcon: "ic_launcher",
      smallIcon: "ic_notification", 
      color: "#251278", 
      tag: 'Notification Tag', 
      group: "group",
      ongoing: false, 
      visibility: "public",

      /* iOS only properties */
      alertAction: 'view', 
      number: "0",

      /* iOS and Android properties */
      title: "Title"
      message: message, 
      playSound: true, 
      soundName: sound,  
    });
  }
```

For cancellation:

```
  static cancelAll() {
    PushNotification.cancelAllLocalNotifications();
  }
```

Comment: Maybe you have a problem with your cancellation of the Notifications... Do you have some dispatched stuff going on that has to do with your notifications... The Word "sometimes" ist most likely something with async running stuff... Could you show us the code that sets and cancels your Notifications?

Comment: For my cancellation of the notifications: static cancelAll() {
    PushNotification.cancelAllLocalNotifications();
  } I schedule with button.It is not async